# SQL Better way to find hours between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, and I have a table with shifts, their start/end datetimes, I want to find all the hours for these shifts that are between 9AM and 3PM.  Shifts cannot be longer than 24 hours (currently).  I've written the query, it works, but it is long.  Taking into account shifts that can start or end on different days made it even longer.  Is there a shorter, more efficient way this could be written?  I have written it so that it ignores the 24 limitation, but still only considers cases where a shift would only overlap 2 days.

```
Select apc.in_punch_time, apc.out_punch_time,

case 
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '09:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') between '09:00' and '15:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) = DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.out_punch_time),MONTH(apc.out_punch_time),day(apc.out_punch_time),9,0,0,0), apc.out_punch_time)
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') >= '09:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '15:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) = DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute,apc.in_punch_time,apc.out_punch_time)
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') between '09:00' and '15:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') >= '15:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) = DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute,apc.in_punch_time, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.in_punch_time),MONTH(apc.in_punch_time),day(apc.in_punch_time),15,0,0,0)) 
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '09:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') >= '15:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) = DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        360
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') < '09:00'  and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '09:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) <> DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        360 
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') between '9:00' and '15:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '09:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) <> DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute, apc.in_punch_time, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.in_punch_time),MONTH(apc.in_punch_time),day(apc.in_punch_time),15,0,0,0))
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') <= '15:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') > '09:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) <> DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute, apc.in_punch_time, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.in_punch_time),MONTH(apc.in_punch_time),day(apc.in_punch_time),15,0,0,0)) + 
        DATEDIFF(minute, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.out_punch_time),MONTH(apc.out_punch_time),day(apc.out_punch_time),9,0,0,0), apc.out_punch_time)
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') >= '15:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') between '09:00' and '15:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) <> DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        DATEDIFF(minute, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(apc.out_punch_time),MONTH(apc.out_punch_time),day(apc.out_punch_time),9,0,0,0), apc.out_punch_time)
    when FORMAT(apc.in_punch_time,'HH:mm') = '00:00' and FORMAT(apc.out_punch_time,'HH:mm') = '00:00' and DATEPART(day,apc.in_punch_time) <> DATEPART(day,apc.out_punch_time) then
        360
    ELSE 0
END hours_between_9_3

from table apc
```

My cases are:

Same Day

1. Shift starts before/at 9, ends between 9 and 3
2. Shift starts at/after 9, ends before 3
3. Shift starts between 9 and 3, ends at/after 3
4. Shift starts before/at 9 and ends after 3

Different Day

1. Shift starts before 9 on Day 1, and ends at before/at 9 on Day 2
2. Shift starts between 9 and 3 on Day 1, ends at/before 9 on Day 2
3. Shift starts between 9 and 3 on Day 1, ends after 9 on Day 2
4. Shift ends at/after 3 on Day 1, ends between 9 and 3 on Day 2
5. Shift starts at midnight on Day 1, ends at Midnight on Day 2

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL SErver? ...

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Here's a rule of thumb for identifing when timestamp ranges (AStart-AEnd, BStart-BEnd) overlap; maybe you'll find it useful:   If (AStart <= BEnd) AND (BStart <= AEnd) these overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my query. It works for any number of days. I am adding three parts:

- the time worked between 09:00 and 15:00 on the first day
- the time worked between 09:00 and 15:00 on the last day (if it's another day than the first day)
- the time worked between 09:00 and 15:00, i.e. 6 hours = 360 minutes, on any days between them

The whole thing is a bit tedious to read (but well, it has been tedious to write, too).

```
with data as
(
  select
    in_punch_time,
    out_punch_time,
    cast (in_punch_time as date) as start_date,
    cast (out_punch_time as date) as end_date,
    cast (in_punch_time as time) as start_time,
    cast (out_punch_time as time) as end_time
  from apc
)
select 
  in_punch_time,
  out_punch_time,
  -- first day
  datediff
  (
    minute,
    case when start_time < '09:00' then
      '09:00'
    when start_time > '15:00' then
      '15:00'
    else
      start_time
    end,
    case when start_date < end_date then
      '15:00'
    when end_time > '15:00' then
      '15:00'
    when end_time < '09:00' then
      '09:00'
    else
      end_time
    end
  ) +
  -- last day (if different from first day)
  case when end_date > start_date and end_time > '09:00' then
    datediff
    (
      minute,
      '09:00',
      case when end_time > '15:00' then
        '15:00'
      when end_time < '09:00' then
        '09:00'
      else
        end_time
      end 
    )
  else
    0
  end +
  -- between days (if any between first and last day)
  case when datediff(day, start_date, end_date) > 1 then
    (datediff(day, start_date, end_date) - 1) * 360 -- minutes
  else
    0
  end as minutes_from_0900_to_1500
from data;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2318dc76adf43cd75e52b378b20b7cbc